# Getting "http error 500" on nginx + wordpress

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx on raspberry pi with the webfiles stores in a external USB stick.

Im getting the error below.

```
- 2023/09/13 19:29:30 [error] 4360#4360: *15 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(/mnt/www/html/web1/wp-includes/version.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /mnt/www/html/web1/wp-load.php on line 62; PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/mnt/www/html/web1/wp-includes/version.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /mnt/www/html/web1/wp-load.php:62
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/www/html/web1/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once()
#1 /mnt/www/html/web1/index.php(17): require('...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /mnt/www/html/web1/wp-load.php on line 62" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.43, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock:",host: "192.168.1.210" "

The wp-load.php file has permission "400"

I appreciate if anyone has the solution.


Changed permission in wp-load.php to 777 but the problem persists.
```

Tried to change the permission of the file to 777

Comment: a course need to just post a simple question in stackflow :/